# Is there a way I can find out online what private jets are parked tonight at a nearby international airport?

Tags: private-jets

There is an international airport about 10 miles from my home. 
Is there any way I can find out online what private jets are parked there tonight? I am not familiar with any of the lingo used here :) so if you could respond in layman's terms I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Would seem like a serious invasion of privacy to me.

Comment: Companies are certainly [tracking corporate jets](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-07-02/hedge-funds-are-tracking-private-jets-to-find-the-next-megadeal) and selling the data to various entities hoping to trade on the information.

Comment: What region are you in? There might be a spotters community active at the airport, logging their sightings online. In the Netherlands, for example, some users of the [Scramble Messageboard](https://forum.scramble.nl/) regularly post which private jets (or "general aviation aircraft") are parked on the apron.

Answer (score 1):

There is not simple list available online, apart from calling the airport and asking them directly. Aircraft are expensive assets so when people own them they tend to keep them under the radar and out of sight and out of the elements by parking them inside a hangar. As an outsider you can only see the outside parked aircraft from the airport fencing.

Determining which aircraft are parked for a short term on an airport is relatively simple to find with the use of an aircraft tracking site such as FlightAware and FR24. On these sites you can enter an airport and see all the official flights in and out of that airport. Flights that have landed but not yet departed will be parked somewhere on the airport.
For example, Lubbock Executive Airpark (Lubbock, Texas, USA)
https://flightaware.com/live/airport/F82/arrivals

Starting from January 2020, the FAA dictates that all airborne flights in the USA should be equipped with an ADS-B transponder, when inside ADS-B airspace, used by the sites above and air traffic control to track flights. So from that day the tracking of smaller aircraft will be greatly improved.

Comment: Not all aircraft will be required to use ADS-B. For example, those without electrical systems are exempt, for obvious reasons.